# Pandas Vlookup True

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

i'm trying to convert a model undertaken in excel over to python for future proofing.

my python experience is about 6months on and off when required for work purposes and believe i've made the issue more complex then it needs to be, due to trying different avenues.

i'm essentially trying to replicate the below:

```
=vlookup('Sheet1'!B2, 'Sheet2'!A1:D100, if('Sheet1'!C2='A',2, if('Sheet1'!C2='B',3,4), TRUE))
```

so sheet 1 is a list of clients and distances.

python mock of data:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Client': ['ABC', 'XYZ', 'KLM'],'Distance': [0.137, 0.103, 0.205], 'Type':['A','B','C']})

  Client  Distance Type
0    ABC     0.137    A
1    XYZ     0.103    B
2    KLM     0.205    C
```

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Distance': [0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.20, 0.25],'A': [1,2,3,4,5], 'B':[0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5], 'C': [2,2.2,2.4,2.6,2.8]})

   Distance  A    B    C
0      0.05  1  0.5  2.0
1      0.10  2  1.0  2.2
2      0.15  3  1.5  2.4
3      0.20  4  2.0  2.6
4      0.25  5  2.5  2.8
```

Expected output:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Client': ['ABC', 'XYZ', 'KLM'],'Distance': [0.137, 0.154, 0.205], 'Type':['A','B','C'], 'Df2val':[3,1, 2.6 ]})

  Client  Distance Type  Df2val
0    ABC     0.137    A     3.0
1    XYZ     0.154    B     1.0
2    KLM     0.205    C     2.6
```

the originally data is ~25k rows, i've reduced this to ~500 based dropping rows that are outside the distance parameters to reduce calculations.

i do have a list of reference points so df['Distance'] will be recalculated 441 times as it runs through the grid overlay.

but am hoping to nest this vlookup and subsequent calculation under a loop/lambda as it runs through these reference points.

i have tried using np.argmin() however kept getting a shape error (one dimension [Df2['val'] column and two dimension [df2[['Distance', 'A']]

i have also looked at np.select using a list of unique values in 'Type' as the conditions and then the arguments to be .loc but that kept erroring as the .loc didnt seem to filter the series correctly.

my current thought process is to use .loc to find the index of the nearest distance and then use another .loc[index number, np.select for the column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a combination of [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) to reshape `df2` to a long format, and [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) to merge on the nearest value by Type:

```
out = pd.merge_asof(df1.reset_index().sort_values(by='Distance'),
                    df2.melt('Distance', var_name='Type', value_name='Df2val')
                       .sort_values(by='Distance'),
                    on='Distance', by='Type', direction='nearest'
                    ).set_index('index').reindex(df1.index)
```

Output:

```
  Client  Distance Type  Df2val
0    ABC     0.137    A     3.0
1    XYZ     0.103    B     1.0
2    KLM     0.205    C     2.6
```

Comment: thats perfect thanks, have fitted to my live data and works a treat. 

i havent got much experience with melt,  only using it a handful of times previous.